# ACH eCheck payment via Forte payment processing, one time tocken and restAPI

Tags: javascript, payment, payment-processing

I am integrating ACH eCheck payment via Forte.js.

The documentation said the first step is getting a one-time security token, which I did, using [forte.js](https://www.forte.net/devdocs/forte.js/forte.js.htm).

Then I should use this token for the [REST API](https://www.forte.net/devdocs/api_resources/forte_api_v2.htm) to make the transaction.

Does anyone know what is the next step after getting the token (it is alerted)?

It's not clear from the documentation how to make a transaction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the REST API with this JSON data

```
{
   "action":"sale", 
   "authorization_amount":1.00,
   "billing_address":{
      "first_name":"Emmett",
      "last_name":"Brown"
   },
   "echeck":{
      "one_time_token":"ott_tq0hemmmtf-zsxgp689rew"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I finished this issue.